# FInd number of rows in given time window in Pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe, a small portion of which is given below:

```
+------+-----+-------------------+-----+
|  name| type|          timestamp|score|
+------+-----+-------------------+-----+
| name1|type1|2012-01-10 00:00:00|   11|
| name1|type1|2012-01-10 00:00:10|   14|
| name1|type1|2012-01-10 00:00:20|    2|
| name1|type1|2012-01-10 00:00:30|    3|
| name1|type1|2012-01-10 00:00:40|   55|
| name1|type1|2012-01-10 00:00:50|   10|
| name5|type1|2012-01-10 00:01:00|    5|
| name2|type2|2012-01-10 00:01:10|    8|
| name5|type1|2012-01-10 00:01:20|    1|
|name10|type1|2012-01-10 00:01:30|   12|
|name11|type3|2012-01-10 00:01:40|  512|
+------+-----+-------------------+-----+
```

For a chosen time window (as an example, let's say `5 days`) , I want to find out how many values of `score` (say `num_values_week`) are there for every `name`. That is, how many values of `score` are there for `name1` between `2012-01-10 - 2012-01-14` , then between `2012-01-15 - 2012-01-29`  and so forth (and same for all other names, like `name2` and so on.)

I want to have cast this information in new PySpark data frame that will have the columns `name`, `type`, `num_values_week`. How can I do this?

In a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58731643/find-number-of-rows-in-a-given-week-in-pyspark) , which I had asked before, I saw how to get counts (of score) when one chooses intervals of one week. But, in this question I want to know how to get counts of scores when one chooses any adjustable value in the time window (like `5 days` or so).

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) with [`DataFrame.groupy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
#df['timestamp']=pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']) #to convert to datetime
new_df=( df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='timestamp',freq='5D'),'name'],sort=False)
          .score
          .count()
          .rename('num_values_week')
          .reset_index() )
print(new_df)
```

**Output**

```
   timestamp    name  num_values_week
0 2012-01-10   name1                6
1 2012-01-10   name5                2
2 2012-01-10   name2                1
3 2012-01-10  name10                1
4 2012-01-10  name11                1
```

---

or [`GroupBy.resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html):

```
new_df=( df.groupby('name',sort=False)
           .resample('5D',on='timestamp')
           .count()
           .score
           .rename('num_values_week')
           .reset_index() )
print(new_df)
```

**Output**

```
     name  timestamp  num_values_week
0   name1 2012-01-10                6
1   name5 2012-01-10                2
2   name2 2012-01-10                1
3  name10 2012-01-10                1
4  name11 2012-01-10                1
```

If you want create a new colum in your original df use `transform`:

```
df['num_values_week']=df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='timestamp',freq='5D'),'name']).score.transform('count')
print(df)

      name   type           timestamp  score  num_values_week
0    name1  type1 2012-01-10 00:00:00     11                6
1    name1  type1 2012-01-10 00:00:10     14                6
2    name1  type1 2012-01-10 00:00:20      2                6
3    name1  type1 2012-01-10 00:00:30      3                6
4    name1  type1 2012-01-10 00:00:40     55                6
5    name1  type1 2012-01-10 00:00:50     10                6
6    name5  type1 2012-01-10 00:01:00      5                2
7    name2  type2 2012-01-10 00:01:10      8                1
8    name5  type1 2012-01-10 00:01:20      1                2
9   name10  type1 2012-01-10 00:01:30     12                1
10  name11  type3 2012-01-10 00:01:40    512                1
```